# Java lang Null Pointer Exception, onCreate

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

this is my code

[image: Maps.java]

intent to Detail.Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);

    namaTxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Detailnama);
    AlamatTxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Detailalamat);
    kontakTxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Detailkontak);
    biayaTxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Detailbiaya);
    img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageDetail) ;
    RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    //RECEIVE DATA
    Intent i=this.getIntent();
    String namabimbel=i.getExtras().getString("namabimbel");
    Integer id_bimbel=i.getExtras().getInt("id_bimbel");
    String Alamat=i.getExtras().getString("Alamat");
    String kontak=i.getExtras().getString("kontak");
    String biaya=i.getExtras().getString("biaya");
    String foto=i.getExtras().getString("foto");
    String kecamatan=i.getExtras().getString("kecamatan");
    Double latitude=i.getExtras().getDouble("latitude");
    Double longitude=i.getExtras().getDouble("longitude");

    //BIND
    namaTxt.setText(namabimbel);
    AlamatTxt.setText(Alamat);
    kontakTxt.setText(kontak);
    biayaTxt.setText(biaya);
    PicassoClient.downloadImage(this,foto,img);
}
```

and then i got error,

> Java Lang null pointer exception on Detail.java:37

```
 //RECEIVE DATA
        Intent i=this.getIntent();
        String namabimbel=i.getExtras().getString("namabimbel");
```

i'm newbie, anyone can help me? thankyou

Comment: You're trying to retrieve data from a null intent. How do you pass the Extras to your new intent?

Comment: You are not adding any extras in Maps.java. Thats why whenever you tries to extract intent extra it is null

Comment: so, i must add extras in maps.java? can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The activities intent does not contain the string extra "namabimbel".

If you are starting this activity from another activity , you need to use

```
putExtra()
```

To add values to the intent.

Comment: can you give me sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your `RECEIVE DATA` block with below code:-

```
//RECEIVE DATA
    Intent i=this.getIntent();
    String namabimbel="";
    Integer id_bimbel=0;
    String alamat="";
    String kontak="";
    String biaya="";
    String foto="";
    String kecamatan="";
    Double latitude= 0.0;
    Double longitude= 0.0;

    if(i.hasExtra("namabimbel"))
        namabimbel=i.getStringExtra("namabimbel");
    if(i.hasExtra("id_bimbel"))
        id_bimbel=i.getIntExtra("id_bimbel",0);
    if(i.hasExtra("Alamat"))
        alamat=i.getStringExtra("Alamat");
    if(i.hasExtra("kontak"))
        kontak=i.getStringExtra("kontak");
    if(i.hasExtra("biaya"))
        biaya=i.getStringExtra("biaya");
    if(i.hasExtra("foto"))
        foto=i.getStringExtra("foto");
    if(i.hasExtra("kecamatan"))
        kecamatan=i.getStringExtra("kecamatan");
    if(i.hasExtra("latitude"))
        latitude=i.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0);
    if(i.hasExtra("longitude"))
        longitude=i.getDoubleExtra("longitude",0);

    //BIND
    namaTxt.setText(namabimbel);
    AlamatTxt.setText(alamat);
    kontakTxt.setText(kontak);
    biayaTxt.setText(biaya);
    PicassoClient.downloadImage(this,foto,img);
```

Comment: Let me update one more option...

Comment: @gita Try edited above answer.

Comment: i try this, but detail information in detail.java doesn't show.

Comment: May be your previous activity has not data or other problem in previous file...

Comment: You can join me on room if you have still problem..

Comment: if i acces detail.java, detail information can show, but if i click on marker and go to detail, detail information doesn't show, sorry for my english

Comment: Put your debug point at `namaTxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Detailnama);` in detail.java and then check on which line app crashed?

Comment: can you help me? if i clikc button daftar, my app will show listview of bimbel, and then if i click on list view, my app wil show detail of bimbel. this is my code of daftar.java

Comment: ok. I can help u..

Comment: can i have your email address?

Comment: it is better if you have anyDesk software in your computer where I remotely debug your app. and email is nitin_it_id@yahoo.co.in .

Comment: ok. i sent you an email